# Why Won't My Fluid Sim Come Back To Life?

Tags: physics

I successfully set up a fluid sim, baked it, and all was well for my project.  But then I wanted to make a change, deleted the cache, and now the domain will not come back to life.

I'm stumped.  So far I've tried:

- Changing the Cache folder location
- Changing the Resolution Divisions
- Changing the Simulation Method
- Changing the Flow emitter size
- Changing the Format Volume
- ... and many other tweaks...

I've also deleted everything in the project except for the domain and the emitter, just to make sure I don't have some weird thing preventing the sim from working.  At this point either I'm totally dumb and just have the wrong setting, or it's a software glitch.

Would love if it someone could open this up and let me know what they see:

[Blender 3.2 Project File](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ihf6v9zcw6yowhh/broken_fluid_sim.blend?dl=0)

[image: Screenshot of Domain settings]

Comment: When I open the file the sim looks, plays and bakes ok. Have you tried changing the Cache Type?

Comment: Thank you for opening that up and taking a look, that was very helpful!  Since it is working on your end I realized it must be something with my setup so I reinstalled Blender and now it working fine.  No idea how 3.2 could have gotten corrupt so fast, it just came out, but regardless I'm good now and thanks!